# Traverse object via dot notated string key

Tags: javascript, object, key

I am not sure as to why this works. It seems to do what I expect however I am unsure how it works. Can someone explain how it manages to find the key and return remap in the console.log?

```js
const data = {
  title: "hello world",
  user: {
    title: 'ruegen',
    app: {
      title: 'my app'
    }
  }

}

const map = {
  'user.title': 'Ruegen',
  'title': 'Title',
  'user.app.title': 'App'
}

Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
  const row = ref(data, key)
  const header = map[key]
  console.log(header, row)
})


function ref(row, key) {
  var headers = key.split(".")
  var row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row))

  headers.forEach(function(header) {
    // console.log('>>', header)
    try {
      row = row[header]
    } catch (err) {
      return
    }
  })
  return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main job is done in `ref` function. You can remve `var row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row))` and it will still works. In that function you split key string to array `headers` (by `key.split(".")`) and then in forEach loop (of headers element) you go into object row by  "row=row[header]" - so at each iteration you replace row by its value at key 'header'. Everything is done in try-catch block so if you key is invalid then you return nothing.

In `Object.keys(map).forEach` you run `ref` with the same data structure but different keys from map object.

The `ref` can be simplified to

```
function ref(row, key) {
  key.split(".").forEach(k => row ? row=row[k] : undefined)
  return row;
}
```

where we replace try-catch block by simple null-checking (which increase code speed for non-valid key) using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
const data = {
  title: "hello world",
  user: {
    title: 'ruegen',
    app: {
      title: 'my app'
    }
  }

}

const map = {
  'user.title': 'Ruegen',
  'title': 'Title',
  'user.app.title': 'App'
}

Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key) {
  const row = ref(data, key)
  const header = map[key]
  console.log(header, row)
})


function ref(row, key) {
  key.split(".").forEach(k => row ? row=row[k] : undefined)
  return row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does shorten it. Won't it mutate the object if I don't deep copy the row?

Comment: @Ruegen it will NOT mutate row (and key)

Comment: Just curious, if it's an object and passed by reference - how is it not?

Comment: `row` is only reference, so by `ref=...` you change only reference (but not change object content). Make test in js console `var a={'x':2}, f= function(b) { b=b.x; return b }; console.log(f(a)); console.log(a);`